# Paste event in ace editor with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, ace-editor

In my mounted hook, I initialize the ace editor as follows:

```
mounted: function() {
 this.$nextTick(() => {
   this.editor = ace.edit('markup-textarea', {
        mode: 'ace/mode/twig',
   });
})
```

Then, in my component, I have a textarea

```
<textarea
id="markup-textarea"
@paste="paste">
```

I noticed that the paste event isn't getting triggered and my paste() function is never called. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: you find solution ?

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding the listener in the component add it in the place where you are creating the editor `this.editor.on("paste", paste)`